# Shadcn Dialog component margin

Tags: tailwind-css, radix, shadcnui

Trying to add some simple margin to left and right of a dialog box when viewing on a mobile screen. No matter where I seem to add mx-5 it doesn't actually work. Any ideas on how to add some margin to a shadcn dialog when viewing on a phone like this?

[Example of Dialog on mobile without margin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WK3Sb.png)

Just about every place I can find on this component I added an mx-5 to add left and right margin but it doesn't seem to have an effect. Also tried sm:mx-5 hoping it would apply on mobile screens but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way around it is first to note that `DialogContent` has a `max-w-lg` around `32rem` *512px* for large screens and `:max-w-md` for smaller screens. To fix this, add a tailwind class `w-11/12` - *making the width not 100%*.

```
 <DialogContent className="w-11/12 sm:max-w-md">
```

Below is an example from the docs - I've added the class to show the example.

```
import { Copy } from "lucide-react"

import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button"
import {
  Dialog,
  DialogClose,
  DialogContent,
  DialogDescription,
  DialogFooter,
  DialogHeader,
  DialogTitle,
  DialogTrigger,
} from "@/components/ui/dialog"
import { Input } from "@/components/ui/input"
import { Label } from "@/components/ui/label"

export function DialogCloseButton() {
  return (
    <Dialog>
      <DialogTrigger asChild>
        <Button variant="outline">Share</Button>
      </DialogTrigger>
      <DialogContent className="w-11/12 sm:max-w-md">
        <DialogHeader>
          <DialogTitle>Share link</DialogTitle>
          <DialogDescription>
            Anyone who has this link will be able to view this.
          </DialogDescription>
        </DialogHeader>
        <div className="flex items-center space-x-2">
          <div className="grid flex-1 gap-2">
            <Label htmlFor="link" className="sr-only">
              Link
            </Label>
            <Input
              id="link"
              defaultValue="https://ui.shadcn.com/docs/installation"
              readOnly
            />
          </div>
          <Button type="submit" size="sm" className="px-3">
            <span className="sr-only">Copy</span>
            <Copy className="h-4 w-4" />
          </Button>
        </div>
        <DialogFooter className="sm:justify-start">
          <DialogClose asChild>
            <Button type="button" variant="secondary">
              Close
            </Button>
          </DialogClose>
        </DialogFooter>
      </DialogContent>
    </Dialog>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful. I also found that if I change w-full to w-5/6 on DialogPrimitive.Content in the component source itself it has the desired effect.

Comment: Yeah! You can do that as well. But I won't advise you to do it at the source component because you may have a different specification in the near future.